# How to select a continuous sample at random from a list?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have input arrays of varying depths, ranging from 20 till 32. I cannot pad them to make them all the same size, so the best option is to randomly select the z-depth of an image at every iteration.

I've read that `numpy.random.choice()` can be used for this but I get a random arrangement of indices, I want a continuous selection.

```
z_values = np.arange(img.shape[0]) # get the depth of this sample
z_rand = np.random.choice(z_values, 20) # create an index array for croping
```

The above gives me:

```
[22  4 31 19  9 24 13  6 20 17 28  8 11 27 14 15 30 16 12 25]
```

Which is not useful for me as they are not continuous and I cannot use it to crop my volume.

Is there any way to get a continuous random sample?

Thanks

Comment: Why can’t you just sort this random output list using sorted()?

Comment: It will still not be continuous. Applying ``sorted()`` on the above gives: ``[4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31]``

Comment: your question can be interpreted in many ways…  what do you mean by "continuous random sample"?  something that emits continuously?  something that isn't only integers?  something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to pick a 20 length slice at random. So just tweak your logic to search for a valid start point at random, and slice to get the result you need.

```
import numpy as np
import random
#pretending this is the image
img = np.array(range(100, 3200, 100))

size_to_slice = 20
if img.shape[0] >= size_to_slice: #make sure you are able to get the length you need
    start = random.randint(0, img.shape[0] - size_to_slice)    
    z_rand = img[start: start + size_to_slice]
else:
    print("selection invalid")
```